# Are there any issues using Ubuntu on an HP Compaq Presario CQ56-103SG?

Tags: wireless, laptop, touchpad

I am planning to buy this laptop [(Compaq-Presario-CQ56-103SG)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004B956KU), which has SuSe Linux SLED11 preinstalled. I want to install Ubuntu 11.04 instead but I'd like to know if the touchpad, the wireless card and everything else works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought it and no, there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  The CQ56 uses the brand new (Read:Six months old) RA5390 chipset from Ralink for the wireless adapter.   I'm working on a .deb package for the RA5390 kernel module from the source code I got from Ralink, but in the meantime you will have to download and compile it manually and enable it with modprobe.

Aside from that, all of the rest of the hardware works flawlessly with the exception of the trackpad's power switch.  I can't figure out how to enable it, but that's okay because it's nothing to just disable the trackpad completely when I have a mouse plugged in.  I'd prefer just double-tapping the little off switch, but you can't win 'em all.

Since it will have SuSe pre-installed, though, you might consider using it to compile all of the kernel modules you're going to need there first before installing ubuntu.

Comment: Does this new wlan chipset cause the network drops from time to time? Thats kind of annoying so am currently using ethernet only.